# How to map file paths when using docker

Tags: gud, path, docker

I'm running code in development using docker.  I do that using the `-v` flag to `docker run` to mount my code in the container.

I've set `directory-abbrev-alist` and configured `compilation-error-regexp-alist-alist` appropriately, so I can click on links in stack traces and jump to the corresponding place in the source code (e.g. in `bt` output from `M-x pdb`).

However, that doesn't give me gud's debug arrow pointing to the current line of the active stack frame.  For example, when I run the `bt` command in pdb, I don't see a window open visiting the appropriate file with the arrow in the fringe pointing at the line of the python stack frame I'm currently on.

In the past I've resorted to creating symlinks on the docker host (for example from `/opt/someproject` to `/home/me/dev/someproject`).  That fixes the problem.  But these may differ from one container to another.  It's inconvenient to keep these up-to-date, not to mention a bit hacky.

How can I fix this using elisp configuration rather than via symlinks?